Are the following spaces homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^1\setminus\{0,1\}$?
I’m working through some topology questions and would like to know whether the following spaces are homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^1\setminus\{0,1\}$, which is the real line with two points removed. Specifically, I would appreciate it if someone could help explain the reasoning behind each answer, whether a homeomorphism exists, and if not, why that’s the case.
a) a union of 3 open intervals $(0,1)\cup (2,3) \cup (4,5)$.
This space consists of three disjoint open intervals. I suspect this is not homeomorphic to
$\mathbb R^1\setminus\{0,1\}$, since the latter consists of exactly two disjoint intervals, but I’m not sure why having three intervals changes things.
b) a triangle without vertices.
This space seems 2-dimensional, whereas $\mathbb R^1\setminus\{0,1\}$ is 1-dimensional. I believe this makes it not homeomorphic.
c) a union of 2 open intervals $(0,1)\cup (4,5)$.
This space consists of two disjoint open intervals. I think this is likely homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^1\setminus\{0,1\}$, since both are made up of two disjoint intervals.
d) a union of 2 open and one closed interval $(0,1)\cup (2,3)\cup [4,5]$.
This space consists of two open intervals $(0,1)\cup (2,3)$. I suspect the presence of the closed interval makes this space not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^1\setminus\{0,1\}$, but I’m unsure why the closed interval changes things in terms of topological properties.
e) a union of 3 closed intervals $[0,1]\cup [2,3]\cup [4,5]$.
This space consists of three closed intervals. I think this is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^1\setminus\{0,1\}$ because it has more than two components and all of them are closed intervals.
I understand that homeomorphisms need to be continuous bijections with continuous inverses.
I’m also aware that the number of components (open vs closed intervals) might be crucial in determining homeomorphism. I’m hoping to get some clarification on these aspects for each of the spaces above.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

To show spaces are not homeomorphic, you have to find a topological invariant that distinguishes them. There is I think only one that you need for this problem: number of connected components is invariant.

you seem to be on the right track, but note that $\mathbb{R}\setminus {0,1}$ has three connected components, viz $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,\infty)$

In topology there many spaces constructed beginning with $\Bbb R$ and their notations often include the character $\Bbb R$ with some extra symbol. So if you meant the real numbers you should use the standard notation: $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb R ^1$.

Apologies, you need that compactness is a topological property as well.

$A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic if there exists a homeomorphism between them, that means a bijection $f:A\to B$ that is continuous with $f^{-1}$ also continuous.
Remark : We won't need this, but since you're only working with subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, you would only need to prove there exists a continuous bijection, the continuity of the reciprocal would then immediately follow (see invariance of domain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).
One mistake that you made in your post is to assume that $\mathbb R\setminus \{0,1\}$ is made of two disjoint intervals when it's actually three : $\mathbb R\setminus \{0,1\} = (-\infty,0)\cup (0,1) \cup (1,+\infty)$. Second of all, just because a shape lives in a 2-dimensional space doesn't mean it can't be homeomorphic to a set that lives in a space with less dimensions. For example, the line of $\mathbb R^2$ defined by $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ is easily homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ with the homeomorphism $f:\begin{cases}\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \times \{0\}\\ x\mapsto (x,0)\end{cases}$.
The first result that could help you is that any two open intervals of $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic (see Topology - interval homeomorphic to another interval).
Here is the general gist to solve each question listed:
a) Yes. $\mathbb R\setminus \{0,1\}$ being a union of 3 disjoint intervals, it will be easy to create a homeomorphism where each interval is sent to a unique interval. (for example: $(-\infty,0)$ is mapped homeomorphically to $(0,1)$, $(0,1)$ is mapped homeomorphically to $(2,3)$, $(1,+\infty)$ is mapped homeomorphically to $(4,5)$).
b) Yes. All that's required to do is to map each disjoint interval of $\mathbb R\setminus \{0,1\}$ to a unique side of your triangle without vertices.
c) No. A homeomorphism preserves connected components (see https://planetmath.org/homeomorphismspreserveconnectedcomponents). Thus any set homeomorphic to $\mathbb R\setminus \{0,1\}$ would also have a total of $3$ connected components, yet $(0,1)\cup (4,5)$ has a total of $2$ connected components.
Edit of d) and e) based on comment:
d) No. Suppose $A = \mathbb R\setminus \{0,1\}$ and $ B = (0,1)\cup (2,3) \cup [4,5]$ are homeomorphic, giving us homeomorphism $f:B\to A$. By preservation of connected components, $f((0,1)), f((2,3))$ and $f([4,5])$ must be each connected, and 2 by 2 disconnected. Since $f$ is bijective (and in particular surjective), each of $f((0,1)), f((2,3))$ and $f([4,5])$ must cover the entire connected component of $A$ it is sent into. Wlog we can suppose $f([4,5]) = (0,1)$, thus $g := f_{|[4,5]}:[4,5]\to (0,1)$ is a homeomorphism between $[4,5]$ and $(0,1)$. (Otherwise consider the composition with a homeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and another open interval).
Since $g$ is continuous and bijective (thus injective) on an interval, it must be either increasing or decreasing. If it is increasing, then $\forall x\in [4,5], g(x) \geq g(4)$, thus $\frac{g(4)}{2}\in (0,1)$ has no inverse image. If it is decreasing, then similarly $\frac{g(5)}{2}\in (0,1)$ has no inverse image.
We have arrived at a contradiction, thus $\mathbb R\setminus \{0,1\}$ and $(0,1)\cup (2,3) \cup [4,5]$ are not homeomorphic.
e) No, easily adapt explanation of d).

For $d$ and $e$, that is not the reason. In their own topologies, both spaces are closed. You are talking about compactness, not closedness.

Also, appealing to invariance of domain here is very deep. All these homeomorphisms and lack thereof can be constructed easily or disproven via simple invariants.

@Malady Thank you for your inputs, I have modified my answer accordingly.

I feel like the argument for d) and e) is a bit too convoluted. You can argue in various ways that a closed interval and open interval are not homeomorphic (e.g. compactness, homogenity etc.) which are purely topological.

@Jakobian It seems like the argument for compactness is also valid, but can only be applied once you've shown that d) being true implies a homeomorphism between a closed and an open interval. Thus the first paragraph I wrote for d) seems prerequired, after that change the second paragraph (which is really not that convoluted in my opinion) into the argument you prefer.

@rafilou2003 +1. Still might be easier to argue from compactness, but this monotonicity argument is nice and classic.

Thank you so much for your answer.
